# Verifying The Divergence Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

Q: "Given the cylindrical region $x^2 + y^2\leq 1 $
,where $ 0\leq z \leq 1 $, and the vector field $\underline{F} = 3x\underline{i} -5z\underline{k}  $, verify the divergence theorem."

For the integral over the surface: Using cylindrical coordinates, with $r=1$ on the surface, gives $x=cos(\phi), y=sin(\phi), z = z$, which makes $\underline{F} = 3cos(\phi)\underline{i} -5z\underline{k}$.

I then have to calculate  $\underline{dS}$, which is what I *think* I'm probably having trouble with, i.e. it's wrong and so is my final answer.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I really can't picture what you've tried.  Notice that in addition to the cylindrical wall where $r=1$, there are circular ends where $z=0,1$ over which the surface integral need to be computed.

Comment: Ah, right. I was semi-aware of that but wasn't sure how to incorporate them into the integral. The question does actually refer to a *closed* surface - so, yeah, I guess that's my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you found a parameterization of the cylindrical wall.  Namely, something to the effect of 
$$
(\cos \theta, \sin \theta, z); \quad \theta \in [0,2\pi], z \in [0,1]
$$
You must, in addition, find and use a parameterization of the top and bottom of the cylinder.  Namely, something to the effect of
$$
(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta, 0); \quad \theta \in [0,2\pi], r \in [0,1]
$$
for the bottom and
$$
(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta, 1); \quad \theta \in [0,2\pi], r \in [0,1]
$$
for the top.

Comment: Thanks. So do I evaluate the integral of curl(F).dS for every 'face', or so to speak?

Comment: It would simply be $F \cdot dS$, not $\nabla \times F \cdot dS$.  But yes, you do this for each face.